# Describing a 2 error correcting BCH code by $c(x)$ codeword iff $β^1$, $β^2$, $β^3$, $β^4$ are roots of $c(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory, reed-muller-codes

I am trying to understand a statement I read about BCH codes. I don't get how we can determine $c(x)$ to be any codeword of BCH of length $2^r -1$ by just checking if $β^1$, $β^2$, $β^3$, $β^4$ are all roots of $c(x)$
P.S: Beta is a primitive element of Galois Field $GF(2^r)$ where r $>=$4 and $c(x)$ is in $K[x]$

Comment: What do you know about BCH codes? Specifically, what is the _definition_ of a 2-error-corercting code that you are using?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I honestly don't have a particular definition for it. All I know what i have watched from videos on YouTube is that BCH codes are a subclass of linear cyclic codes that are used to decoding multiple errors and for each number of error there is a specific way of designing the code probably by using elements from Galois field  . what I am learning is codes of length 15 which have minimal distance of 5 that's why it is a 2-error correcting code and generated by minimal polynomials for $β^1$  and $β^3$.

Comment: What Dilip said. In math (as well as its applications) to test whether an object $z$ is an element of the set $S$ it is imperative that you have a definition (= a precise description) of the set $S$. For me it would be the definition of the double-error-correcting BCH code that the polynomial $c(x)$ is a word, iff $c(\beta^i)=0$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. The first theorem is then that (as we assume $c(x)$ to have coefficients in $GF(2)$ it suffices to check $c(\beta)$ and $c(\beta^3)$.